# How to get Python binding to recompiled libcamera?

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-4, cross-compilation, libcamera

I am trying to recompile `libcamera`, as I will be changing some stuff in it and I would therefore like to install it manually.
The compilation and installation are successful, but I am not able to import it into python.
I know there is a extra package `python3-libcamera` in the Raspberry Pi OS repos, but I cannot install that e.g. on a Ubuntu workstation.

Is there a way to recreate the python bindings?

RESOLUTION: Thanks @tttapa, I needed to enable the 'pycamera' option in the meson build.
Additionally I also needed to add the path it installed to to the `PYTHONPATH`, as it was not able to import elsewise.
In my case it installed to `/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/python3.10/site-packages` so I needed to `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/python3.10/site-packages`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable the `pycamera` option when building libcamera:

https://github.com/raspberrypi/libcamera/blob/f30ad033c911f874b4304938dc5a4c2e9ee07aa2/meson_options.txt#L62

Comment: Thanks, though additionally I also needed to add the directory it was installing to to the "PYTHONPATH", otherwise it wouldn't work.